# Trying to implement OpenId Connect with Keycloak but I always get "Code not valid"

Tags: realm, keycloak, openid-connect, openid

Just getting started with Keycloak for authentication with OpenIdConnect. I have created a `test-realm` on my local Keycloak server and I'm trying to authenticate using the `admin-cli` client under it. Under Settings for `admin-cli` under `test-realm`, I have set the following:

Client Protocol: Open Id Connect
Access Type: Confidential
Direct Access Grants Enabled: ON
Service Accounts Enabled: ON

And under `Fine Grain OpenID Connect Configuration` > `Valid Request URIs` I added `*` for now (doesn't help even if I add the proper redirect URL i.e. `localhost:9999`).

However, every time I try to obtain the `/token` I always get

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Code not valid"
}
```

What's strange is that when I change the `grant_type` to `client_credentials`, I receive the access token in the response perfectly. But change that back to `authorization_code` and I get that error. Here's the curl call that I make:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/test-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token \
  --header 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW4tY2xpOjEwMWRkOWJjLTc1NjItNDBhNy04OWI1LWJhOTUxMWJiYmQ5ZA==' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  --data grant_type=authorization_code \
  --data code=IvGEFwk0LRBSuQSJgHHrZsWYPKCloLh6L8N7nOGhnUz \
  --data redirect_uri=http://localhost:9999
```

where `localhost:8080` is my local keycloak server

Is there something wrong with my configuration?

Comment: Where did you get that code "IvGEFwk0LRBSuQSJgHHrZsWYPKCloLh6L8N7nOGhnUz" from?

Comment: That code was generated by my parent application which calls keycloak

Comment: Did you already had a look at https://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/keycloak-authorization-code-grant-example/ particular at the last call

Comment: I did - that was my starting point actually! So, I decided to retry my request:

`http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/test-realm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?scope=openid%20email&response_type=code&client_id=admin-cli&redirect_uri=http://localhost:9999&state=0ogdEPwEqt3C1xY0pdZX2ofnVFROCeUXA65PNlJhgBK&nonce=zONxaqDrSe7ttRzq1BoEN5NbA7BDg2ygMoCUIYLvpgD`

And I now I get `Invalid parameter: redirect_uri` - I guess this is why I get the error in the first place. But the `redirect_uri` that I pass and in the keycloak client config are the same, why would this still happen?

Comment: Can it be encoding? try &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost or &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9999 (technically if you have Valid Request URIs=* and web origins +) it should have accepted

Comment: So! I debugged some more! Turns out I was passing along an extra query-param `nonce` which is probably not required. But when I post that URL into my browser, I no longer see the `redirect_uri` error but now it asks me to login to my `test-realm` - I use my admin credentials which I use to log into `master` realm but it says `incorrect user/password` -- am i doing this right?

Comment: No, the admin belongs to the master realm, does not belong to test-realm, create a user on test-realm and tried it out with that user

Comment: You're right about that! That does work! And keycloak sets up the redirect correctly. However, the `/token` endpoint still says "Inavlid format" for the code.

Comment: Okay, so I figured this out I think!!! I ran a `nc -lk localhost 9999` and captured the request that was being made and i saw this:

`GET /?state=dkCuH9njiQhUNzYq1eQcKiZNqAsM6lOWtG7LpEsDF4o&session_state=fb2969f0-0906-4e97-ac14-43293597d844&code=3d663ace-22cd-4eec-a1ec-ff5d43ae4517.fb2969f0-0906-4e97-ac14-43293597d844.b17dec7a-c628-4502-86df-937280fd824b`

When I used this `code` --> `3d663ace-22cd-4eec-a1ec-ff5d43ae4517.fb2969f0-0906-4e97-ac14-43293597d844.b17dec7a-c628-4502-86df-937280fd824b` in my `/token` I got the correct response!!!

But why does this happen?

Comment: Glad tot you find out, I was about to write to look at that part because I was looking at some tests that I have that test the standard work flow. Well it looks like your parent application was generating the wrong code, just look at the size of the one generated by keycloak compared with your original

Comment: I think what really turned it around was turning on the "Standard Flow Enabled" option! After that it was all a matter of passing in the correct parameters!

Comment: I wrongly assume that you had that enabled